# Using an average of VADER and textBlob's sentiment polarity gives me a more accurate result, why?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob, vader

I have a manually labelled set of ~120K tweets. If I use VADER's compound score it only matches the manual labelling for ~24% of the records, textblob matches ~35% of the manually labelled record. If I take Vaders compound score and textblobs score and add then together and divide by 2 the resulting sentiment result matches the manual labelling ~70% of the time. Is there any reason for why its more accurate or is it just coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stumbling upon the idea behind [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). More often than not, putting multiple models together and combining their predictions leads to better results. Your implementation could be thought of as an equally weighted soft-voting ensemble. For more examples and additional implementations, the [scikit-learn Voting Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier) docs are great.